# Is it possible to complete the Crimson Room?

Tags: crimson-room

I decided to play the [Crimson Room](http://www.albinoblacksheep.com/games/room), but at one point you need to go to a url:

```
http://takagism.fasco-cs.com/yellow_chamber.html
```

This page has gone away over the last 10 years, is it possible to progress without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One seems to be unable to complete it from the site you have linked, since it has the version with the random code. If you play it from [this source](http://www.gtds.net/Crimson-Room/), it seems to have the code being hardcoded to 1994. I played it 3x to the safe and it accepted the same code every time.